# Why does my method not work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

The question is as follows.

> A golfer is playing golf facing an inclined plane of inclination angle $\theta$. When he strikes the ball, the ball flies towards the inclined plane. The ball left the ground at an angle $\phi$ relative to the inclined plane. What is the value of $\phi$ at which the ball can land the farthest distance along the incline? Neglect air resistance and assume the inclined plane is infinitely long.

This is taken from the 2019 CAP Prize exam. The solution is posted officially, but I was confused as to why my method is incorrect, which roughly goes like this:
Treat the inclined plane as the $x$-axis. You then have a normal projectile motion problem except there is a negative horizontal acceleration. Then, solve for $\phi$ by setting the final horizontal velocity to $0$ (which should maximize the distance travelled). I obtain an answer of $2\tan\phi = \tan(90-\theta)$ . Interestingly enough, $\tan2\phi = \tan(90-\theta)$ gives rise to the correct answer, but I’ve been trying to troubleshoot for a while now and can’t find anything. Does my logic not work or is it a calculation error?

Answer (score 1):

> Then, solve for phi by setting the final horizontal velocity to 0 (which should maximize the distance travelled).

I don't think this is correct. This will calculate the distance that results in the ball hitting the ground perpendicularly, which is not necessarily where distance is maximized. Think of when the ground is flat; distance is maximized when the ball strikes the ground at a 45⁰ angle.

You should calculate the range at a launch angle $\varphi$ and then maximize that using standard calculus methods.